# Redirecting from Controller to standard list view page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, redirect

I'm using a custom_object and once the user save I want that page to redirect to list view page but what is happening is that right after i click save button i see the white blank screen with the following URL

> https://XXXX.visual.force.com/apex/Employee?retURL=%2Fa00%2Fo&save_new=1&sfdc.override=1

Here is the code I have used:

I have tried this code:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult anySObjectSchema = Employee__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
String objectIdPrefix = anySObjectSchema.getKeyPrefix();
PageReference pageReference = new PageReference('/'+objectIdPrefix+'/o');
pageReference.setRedirect(true);
return pageReference;
```

and this code: (hard code the prefix) still does not work:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/a00/o'); 
pageRef.setRedirect(true); 
return pageRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use inside your command button or link
 `oncomplete="window.open('/a00', '_blank', height=400,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,me‌​nubar=no,scrollbars=‌​1', 1);"`

OR
Using a commandlink because you can set the target

```
`   public PageReference ReturnToList(){
    //do something here or no
    return new PageReference('/' + Employee__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
    }`
```

Comment: i do not like to use any javascript and i'm sure there is better way of doing than this.

Comment: Hi Nick, if you don't like js then the second option should do it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Still have the same issue after I click save button, I see the blank white screen with the url I posted in my question

Comment: That's weird, those are two valid ways to accomplish what you need. I use these approaches all the time. I don't think you problem is in the code. I would check user permissions or page security. Good luck!